# Bootstrap 5 navbar dropdown and hamburger button are not working?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am working on a blogger.com's theme leveraging bootstrap 5.
The page seems to work well except that the navbar dropdown is not working. And if I test the browser in mobile width, the navbar's hamburger menu does NOT collapse after it is expanded.

In my chrome browser's inspect window, I do not see any javascript error. [image]

Perhaps I am missing some bootstrap libraries to be included?

The site is https://theme-lab-center.blogspot.com/ (Update: The problem has been resolved with using Bootstrap 5.2 instead of 5.3. The latest source code of this page will not reflect the original problem.)

This is the html code related to the navbar:

```
<a class='navbar-brand' href='/'>LOGO</a>
<button aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation' class='navbar-toggler' data-bs-target='#navbarSupportedContent' data-bs-toggle='collapse' type='button'>
<span class='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
</button>
<div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarSupportedContent'>
<ul class='navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0'>
  <li class='nav-item'><a aria-current='page' class='nav-link active' href='/'>Home</a></li>
  <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='#'>Link</a></li>
  <li class='nav-item dropdown'><a aria-expanded='false' class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' data-bs-toggle='dropdown' href='#' role='button'>Dropdown</a>
    <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
      <li><a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Action</a></li>
      <li><a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Another action</a></li>
      <li><hr class='dropdown-divider'/></li>
      <li><a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Something else here</a> 
     </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link disabled'>Disabled</a></li>
</ul>
<form action='/search' class='d-flex' method='GET' role='search'>
<input aria-label='Search' class='form-control me-2' name='q' placeholder='Search' type='search'/>
<button class='btn btn-secondary' type='submit'>Search</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include Bootstrap’s JS along with Bootstrap's CSS. You have two options:

**OPTION 1: Include Bootstrap's JavaScript bundle**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**OPTION 2: Include Bootstrap's JavaScript and [PopperJS](https://popper.js.org/) separately**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

See the snippet below.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class='navbar-brand' href='/'>LOGO</a>
      <button aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent' aria-expanded='false' aria-label='Toggle navigation' class='navbar-toggler' data-bs-target='#navbarSupportedContent' data-bs-toggle='collapse' type='button'>
          <span class='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
        </button>
      <div class='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarSupportedContent'>
        <ul class='navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0'>
          <li class='nav-item'><a aria-current='page' class='nav-link active' href='/'>Home</a></li>
          <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link' href='#'>Link</a></li>
          <li class='nav-item dropdown'><a aria-expanded='false' class='nav-link dropdown-toggle' data-bs-toggle='dropdown' href='#' role='button'>Dropdown</a>
            <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
              <li><a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Action</a></li>
              <li><a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class='dropdown-divider' />
              </li>
              <li><a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Something else here</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='nav-item'><a class='nav-link disabled'>Disabled</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form action='/search' class='d-flex' method='GET' role='search'>
          <input aria-label='Search' class='form-control me-2' name='q' placeholder='Search' type='search' />
          <button class='btn btn-secondary' type='submit'>Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have the bootstrap 5.3 JS already included. However, I tried changing the Bootstrap version to 5.2.3, it works! 

<script crossorigin='anonymous' integrity='sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js'/>

Comment: @SSuen Please accept my answer if it was helpful in any way. :)

Comment: it turns out that the problem is slightly more complex. I need to include popper.min.js to get the hamburger button fully working!

Comment: @SSuen You don't need to include `popper.min.js` if you include `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` (i.e., Bootstrap's JavaScript bundle). You need to include `popper.min.js` if you include just `bootstrap.min.js`. That's probably why Bootstrap `5.2.3` works while `5.3.0` doesn't. It has nothing to do with the Bootstrap version. It probably has to do with the fact that you didn't include the bundle when using `5.3.0`.

Comment: I did include the bundle.min.js in the first place. That's why I was rather puzzled. Anyway, I suspected I did something silly in including the wrong combo of js and I cannot trace back in time what I did wrong! thanks anyay.

Comment: I had this issue, I had bootstrap bundle and popper added after each other. I kept bootstrap bundle. and it is working fine.